# Render an animation with 2 different cameras but at the same time

Tags: animation, camera

I have two different cameras covering my animation. Is there any way that I can make them both render at the same time so that I don't have to render each view out manually?

Comment: Is the goal some kind of stereoscopic view, or are the cameras covering different aspects of the scene?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy your scene and render both scenes. To do so go to the top of your window and click the + next to your scene and choose *Link Objects*.

Next select the inactive camera and make it active.

Then go to compositing and check *Use Nodes*. Now delete the *Composite* node and add another *Render Layer* node (*Add > Input > Render Layer*).

Select the newly created scene in the new *Render Layer* node.

Now add two *File Output* nodes (*Add > Output > File Output*), and input each of the renderlayer nodes into an output node.

Lastly, in each of the output nodes, navigate to the paths that you want each camera location to be saved to. But be careful not to choose the same path for both nodes, because one output will overwrite the other.

All that's left is to hit render animation and watch the magic happen.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is even faster solution to do this. It might not cover your question properly due to the fact you said you wouldn't like to render them both manually, but in that case, keep in mind that you are loosing a lot of time rendering in this way.

I had the same situation before with some scenes, and the answer above (from palkonimo) is correct, but it might slow down your rendering time drastically due to the fact that your PC is using either CPU or GPU (depends which one is set as default) to render the whole scene together. This means your PC will use 50% of power (for each camera) to render both of these two render layers separately.

Faster solution is to open two Blender windows, and open your scene in each one of them. Than, set one of your Blender windows (first camera) to render via CPU, and in the other Blender window set your scene (second camera) to render via GPU. This will boost up your rendering speed in double (if you have a decent GPU of course). Its just a proposal that works as well, but a lot faster.

I advise you though, not to do this if your PC is not well ventilated, so watch out for your hardware temperatures! Also keep in mind to have enough powerful PSU to do this, because both CPU and GPU are going to be working on 100%. I should also emphasize that this works only with Cycles as much as I know.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is another way - set up Multi-view cameras. This will result in multiple frames being rendered for each frame of the animation, one from each camera and each with a suffix specific to that camera.

See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102118/29586 for details of how this is set up.